# How to sync Google Calendar with Apple Desktop Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization

Is there a way to sync my Google Calendar with my Apple Calendar (on my Mac desktop and iPod touch)?

Comment: I've tried this a couple times, and never got it to work right. I'd love to see a good solution.

Comment: This question was closed (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/506/how-do-i-synchronise-multiple-google-calendars-to-my-windows-mobile-phone-close), so this one should be too.

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: @akira, since Google calendar is a webapp, this question would fit on either site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into settings on Google Calendar, you'll find a URL which you can use to connect to Google Calendars. These can be entered into iCal and they will be kept in sync

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=99358#ical

Answer (score 2):

[According to this](http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/google-calendar-now-supports-apple-ical.html), it appears that Google supports Apple iCal. There's a utility you can download and install with will configure iCal to work with Google Calendars.